# How to map dropDownlist to enum in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have bound a drop down list to the enum of days of week like this:

```
    private void BindDayOfWeek()
    {
        this.ddlDayOfWeek.DataSource = GetWeekDays();
        this.ddlDayOfWeek.DataBind();
    }

    private List<DayOfWeek> GetWeekDays()
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<DayOfWeek>().ToList();
    }
```

Now I want to read the int value of the selected week day (from dropdown list) which was in enum DayOfWeek i.e. if I select "Sunday" from dropdown, I should be able to pick the int value of "Sunday" in the enum DaysOfWeek (NOT ddlDayOfWeek.selectedValue OR SelectedIndex)

How can I do that without a switch and if (Which I think can be one way)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the `SelectedValue` is a string you need to parse it first to `int`. Then you just need to cast it to `DayOfWeek`:

```
if(ddlDayOfWeek.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
    int selectedDay = int.Parse(ddlDayOfWeek.SelectedValue);
    DayOfWeek day = (DayOfWeek) selectedDay;
}
```

If you don't separate the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`(what you should) you can parse the `string` "Sunday" which is displayed in the `DropDownList` to `DayOfWeek` via `Enum.Parse`:

```
DayOfWeek selectedDay = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), ddlDayOfWeek.SelectedValue);
```

**Edit**: Here's an approach how you can set the `DataTextField/DataValueField` from the enum:

```
var weekDays = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<DayOfWeek>()
    .Select(dow => new { Value = (int)dow, Text = dow.ToString() })
    .ToList();
ddlDayOfWeek.DataSource = weekDays;
ddlDayOfWeek.DataTextField = "Text";
ddlDayOfWeek.DataValueField = "Value";
ddlDayOfWeek.DataBind();
```

Comment: I see the point. Even though ddlDayOfWeek still has week names in DatavalueField, so DayOfWeek selectedDay will be "Sunday" (from your 2nd set of code). How can I get int value of "Sunday" from Enum ?

Comment: @sdeep: with your current approach my second approach works. If you want to use the `int` as `Value` and the day-name as `Text` you can use the query that i have edited into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void BindDayOfWeek()
{
    this.ddlDayOfWeek.DataSource = GetWeekDays();
    this.ddlDayOfWeek.DataTextField = DayOfWeek;
    this.ddlDayOfWeek.DataValueField = (int)DayOfWeek.ToString();
    this.ddlDayOfWeek.DataBind();
}
```

Change your bind code to the above. This way the selected item of the drop down list, as all items, will have a text value that will be shown to the user and a value for this value, which you will can get it server side. The property value of the item, will give you the number of the selected day.

Comment: @Stefano, no I haven't tested it. Why? Do you see any error? The only thing I am not absolute is the names of the properties. DataTextField and DataValueField

Comment: @Christos DayOfWeek doesn't have tostring() methods.

Comment: @sdeep, I am sorry. I corrected my post. Thanks. Is that works know? Please let me know, if there is any problem.

Comment: See Tim's usage of DataTextField / DataValueField. They should be the name of data source properties.