# Foreign Key ID Conversion (C# to SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a local database I've created (SQL Server), connected to a Library application I'm working on, which has several tables / records - in this particular case, I will be referring to the **Books** table:

```
ID (PK),
Name,
Author,
CategoryID (FK),
Price
```

And also the **Category** table:

```
ID,
CategoryName
```

What I'm trying to do is: I have a 'New Book Record' form; once the book details are filled in and the "Save" button is clicked, it generates (via insert query) the record on my local Library App DB, in the **Books** table.

As an example of the issue, when trying to save the new record (I'm submitting 'History' in the **Category** textbox) the app shows an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int

As I understand, the issue is that History is not being converted to the `CategoryID` (FK) that is in the `Books` table, which is reflected as

```
ID: 4 - CategoryName: History
```

in the `Category` table. The below code is what I've done so far, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename= C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Library System Project.mdf ;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

string Query = "insert into Books (BookName, BookAuthor, CategoryID, ClassificationID, BookAvailabilityQuantity, Price) values ('" + this.txtName.Text.Trim() + "','" + this.txtAuthor.Text.Trim() + "','" + this.txtCategory.Text.Trim() + "','" + this.txtClassification.Text.Trim() + "','" + this.txtAvailabilityQuantity.Text.Trim() + "','" + this.txtPrice.Text.Trim() + "');";

SqlConnection DBCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
SqlCommand DBCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, DBCon);
SqlDataReader DBReader;

try
{
    DBCon.Open();
    DBReader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader();
    MessageBox.Show("New book record added to the system.", "Library System", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

    while (DBReader.Read())
    {
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    // *** If you're going to be opening a connection be sure to close it ***
    // *** Finally blocks work well for this ***
    DBCon.Close();

    this.txtName.ResetText();
    this.txtAuthor.ResetText();
    this.txtCategory.ResetText();
    this.txtClassification.ResetText();
    this.txtAvailabilityQuantity.ResetText();
    this.txtPrice.ResetText();
}
```

Comment: What Value do you enter in Category textbox? This error is because you enter a non-numeric value in this textbox which is not convertable to int.

Comment: As said, in my test, I input 'History' (CategoryID: 4) within the Category textbox.

What I want is that, when I put 'History' in the Category textbox, the application understands that it should be reflect ID 4 in Category table.

I may be confusing things, apologies if so as I'm still a coding newbie.

To re-iterate, I don't want to have to put a Category ID (integer) in the Category Textbox - I want to be able to type in the Category Type, such as History, and for the application to understand and convert the value in the DB itself

Comment: That's the problem. You should input `4` not `History` in that textbox. Better way is making an `Enum` and map each CategoryName to a value and then save the value into DB table

Comment: Do you by chance know how I can implement an Enum, please? I think, as you explained, that's the method I was trying to explain, just not sure how to implement it.

Thank you

Comment: Please see this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399124/how-to-map-dropdownlist-to-enum-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399124/how-to-map-dropdownlist-to-enum-in-c)

Comment: Will check it out. Thank you @Amir

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: The field: Category should be a dropdown that will be populated with the data from the table: Category. Than you will map the Id column with the ValueMember and DisplayMember = CategoryName and never use concatenated string to pass your parameters in a SQL command this put your code in a high vulnerability to SQL Injection attacks.